# Script exits on line calling tput when invoked from SecureCRT

Tags: linux, bash

I am using locale en_US.UTF8  When using the bash -v script_name.sh it gets to a variable that has single quotes - example below.  Have tried manually setting UTF8 on securecrt session, validated all locale settings are en_US.

**When it errors out there is no error message, just the last variable value and then back to terminal prompt**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

CODE EXAMPLE

```
#!/bin/bash
....some text eliminated ....
set -e

########## Variable ##########
SUDO=""
BASH_C="bash -c"
SLEEP_SEC=10
LOG_OUTPUT="/tmp/${0##*/}$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M)"
CURRENT_USER="$(id -un 2>/dev/null || true)"
INSTALLATION_DIR="/srv/app/ilp-connector"
CONNECTOR_REPO="https://github.com/interledgerjs/ilp-connector.git"
########## Nodejs ##########
NODEJS_RPM_URL="https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x"
NODEJS_DEB_URL="https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x"
########## Certbot ##########
CERTBOT_AUTO_URL="https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto"
########## Constant ##########
SUPPORT_DISTRO=(debian ubuntu fedora centos)
#Color Constant
RED="tput setaf 1"

SINGLE QUOTES HERE ->>>>  GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
ERROR SECTION ->>>>  tput setaf 2
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what's going wrong here. Also, those are backquotes (aka backticks), not regular single-quotes, and they do something very different -- they execute their contents as a command, then use its output as the value at that point in the command line. So rather than setting the variable `GREEN` to the string "tput setaf 2", it sets it to the output of the command `tput setaf 2`. Is that not what you intended?

Comment: If the backquotes bother you, in bash you can use `$()`, e.g. `$(tput setaf 2)`. Actually it’s even better because you can nest an expression inside another, unlike backquotes.

Comment: True, they are backticks.  That was my oversight.  Not my script.  When the scriot is run and reaches this variable RED and it has backticks it exits prematurely.  I changed them to double quotes and it moves past that point and fails on the next line.  The real question is why is bash failing when trying to assign a command to variable using backticks?

Comment: I will try using the $() and see if that fixes the issue.  I understand this is a deprecated style so it may not be compatible?

Comment: I have tried the $().  The following is the output from that section.  Returns to temerinal immediately when there is more in the script so it basically errors out without an error message.

    [root@ilp01 useruser]# bash -v ilp-install.sh 
    #!/bin/bash --utf8
    .........eliminated some code for brevity........
    SUPPORT_DISTRO=(debian ubuntu fedora centos)
    #Color Constant
    RED=$(tput setaf 1)
    [root@ilp01 useruser]#

Comment: Don't use `set -e` if you don't want your script to exit for surprising/unintended/bad reasons. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), and particularly the exercises within.

Comment: In this case, if your `TERM` isn't set such that `tput` can generate a color code for it, that copy of `tput` can fail. And `set -e` makes *any* nonzero exit an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution albeit partial, is that the SecureCRT session or shell session in some way was not parsing the script properly.  As soon as I used the VMware console and opened up a terminal it started to work....    So Ill just use that and drop the issue at this point.  Somewhat frustrating but it now I know.

Comment: figured it out.  It was secureCRT default terminal options.  I changed it to XTERM and Linux.  Both work.  Closing discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
```

...to...

```
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2) ||:
```

`:` is a synonym for `true`. This makes a failure from `tput` be ignored, so your script continues to execute (even with `set -e`) even if the color code for green can't be detected.

<sub>That said, I **strongly** advise against using `set -e`; see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for an in-depth discussion.</sub>